# Ambidentate Behavior of Cyanide

Tags: organic-chemistry

Why do haloalkanes give alkyl cyanides when treated with KCN but give alkyl isocyanide with AgCN?

Comment: It is because KCN(K is an alkali metal) is majorly ionic but AgCN is majorly covalent(due to metal-carbon bond as Ag is a transition metal). So in AgCN, N acts a nucleophile.

Comment: Note the mouseover hint at down pointing grey triangle as the default reason for the question downvoting:  *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."* Just in case you would wondering why the question got downvotes or was even closed.

Comment: Looks like homework: https://www.toppr.com/ask/en-us/question/haloalkanes-react-with-kcn-to-form-alkyl-cyanides-as-main-product-while-agcn-forms-isocyanides/

Comment: Here is a [review](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acsomega.9b04073) to start researching. "Nucleophilic isocyanation was first described in the late 19th century, but the advancement and extension of this chemistry are still limited. This is probably due to the difficulty in the selective formation of isonitrile over the thermodynamically and kinetically favored isomer, nitrile. Moreover, excess amounts of toxic metal cyanides are usually required for this transformation. Currently, the relatively reliable dehydration of formamides is most often chosen for the synthesis of isonitriles."

Comment: Thanks Karsten, I had Googled the question but wasn't satisfied with the explanation. Maurice's answer is much more complete. Will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\ce{KCN}$ substance is made of two ions : $\ce{K^+}$ and $\ce{CN^-}$ The active ion is cyanide, and the active atom in cyanide ion is the carbon atom, which is charged $-1$. This negative C atom attacks haloalkanes to produce alkylcyanide.
On the contrary, $\ce{AgCN}$ is not made of two ions. It is not soluble in water. The bond $\ce{Ag-C}$ is mainly covalent. So the active atom in $\ce{AgCN}$ is the outer $\ce{N}$ atom. When interacting with a haloalkane, the $\ce{N}$ atom has a free doublet which can attack it via a $\ce{S_N2}$ mechanism to produce an isocyanide.

Comment: I tried to find out what the structure of AgCN is in solution (and in what solvent it is soluble in) but came up short. In the crystal structure, AgCN forms linear chains with similar Ag-C and Ag-N bond lengths, so the argument does not work in the solid state. AgCN is insoluble in water, but the complex $\ce{Ag(CN)2-}$ is soluble.

Comment: How can $\ce{AgCN}$ make linear chains, if $\ce{Ag-C}$ and $\ce{Ag-N}$ have similar bond lengths ? Does it mean that the X-ray structure is made of long and parallel chains looking like $\ce{Ag-C-N···Ag-C-N···Ag-C-N··· Ag··}$, etc. This does not prevent the $\ce{N}$ atom to attack the haloalkane to produce an alkyl  isocyanide.

Comment: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ic9714697 shows AuCN and describes AgCN as very similar, "consists of rows of AgCN chains with alternating long Ag−C = 2.15(6) and short Ag−N = 1.86(8) Å." So the bond lengths are significantly different in the solid, but both shorter than a van der Waals contact.